# Android Dev SQL vs JSON

Tags: android, sql, json

I'm writing an Android app that I want to use in conjunction with a band website I've developed. The website uses a SQL database to hold information such as blogs, band member information, tour dates, etc.

What data access method would make the most sense to use? I've looked at Andriod dev on tekpub and JSON data access is incredibly easy, however would it make sense to parse the database into JSON just for Android access?

Is there a good way to hit the SQL database as is? Any advice, tutorial links, or examples would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard to use JSON or XML to transfer data from a server to an android client.

Giving direct access to the SQL from the devices would be a bad idea as it would

- expose a large security hole
- make your data base schema more difficult to change (too many clients would rely directly on its structure)
- just not work in most cases as database driver are not meant to be used this way, they often use a stable channel to communicate with the database server.